# Form design issue with bootstrap 3

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I do not write bootstrap code but some how i manage to do it now but form does not looks good. two issue is there. How to fix my issue. thanks

1) buttons are not properly aligned.
2) how to create gap between two buttons.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                <label for="textbox1">Phone No</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="textbox1" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                <label for="textbox2">Post Code</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="textbox2" type="text" />
            </div>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  .m{
    margin:10px; 
  }
 </style>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: green">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleTextarea">Example textarea</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label for="textbox1">Phone No</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="textbox1" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label for="textbox2">Post Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="textbox2" type="text" />
                </div>
                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary m"  value="Reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> </body>
</html>
```

check this out fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sh8k20xx/

Comment: i test your code but still textbox left align and button left align not same.

Comment: Phone No and phone no textbox should be in same line but your sample showing two in different line one after one....which i do not want.

Comment: textboxes start and button start should be same position but when i test your sample i saw button move more little to right side.

Comment: you cant make the textboxes to appear side by side in this format of bootstrap fro that you have to use grid system  and change the whole code hope this helps

Comment: in this format what you have used its uses block inline that is why there are line breaks in it maybe what youo are syaing for that you have to used bootstrap grid system you can give this an accepted answer